# Let $\sum =\{a, b\}$ and $L =\{aa, bb\}.$ Use set notation to describe $L$ complement.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computability

So I know that I want to find $\sum^* - L$ , but I am at a loss regarding how to express that in compact set notation. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly does $\sum^{*}$ mean here?

Comment: @雨が好きな人 All words in the alphabet $\Sigma$

Answer (score 1):

{ x in $\Sigma^*$ : x is not aa and x is not bb }

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{l}\bar L = {\sum ^*} - L = \{ w|w \in {\{ a,b\} ^*}and\;w \notin \{ aa,bb\} \} \\\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; = \{ \lambda ,a,b,ab,ba\}  \cup \{ w|w \in {\{ a,b\} ^*}and\;|w| > 2\} \end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiFu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaaceWGmb
% GbaebacqGH9aqpcqGHris5daahaaWcbeqaaiaacQcaaaGccqGHsisl
% caWGmbGaeyypa0Jaai4EaiaadEhacaGG8bGaam4DaiabgIGiolaacU
% hacaWGHbGaaiilaiaadkgacaGG9bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaGGQaaaaOGa
% amyyaiaad6gacaWGKbGaaGjbVlaadEhacqGHjiYZcaGG7bGaamyyai
% aadggacaGGSaGaamOyaiaadkgacaGG9bGaaiyFaaqaaiaaysW7caaM
% e8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caaMe8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caaMe8UaaGjbVlaays
% W7caaMe8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caaMe8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caaMe8UaaGza
% VlaaygW7caaMb8UaaGjbVlaaysW7caaMe8Uaeyypa0Jaai4EaiabeU
% 7aSjaacYcacaWGHbGaaiilaiaadkgacaGGSaGaamyyaiaadkgacaGG
% SaGaamOyaiaadggacaGG9bGaeyOkIGSaai4EaiaadEhacaGG8bGaam
% 4DaiabgIGiolaacUhacaWGHbGaaiilaiaadkgacaGG9bWaaWbaaSqa
% beaacaGGQaaaaOGaamyyaiaad6gacaWGKbGaaGjbVlaacYhacaWG3b
% GaaiiFaiabg6da+iaaikdacaGG9baaaaa!9D2F!
$$